# Neat way to check first line of a file before reading CSV

Tags: python, csv, io

I'm searching for a clever way to check the first line of a file before reading it as a csv file. I want to check if there's a `# coding: xxx` line so that I can decode read data accordingly. But if there is no such line, the first line might already contain a dataset. Seeking seems so brutal to me, I was hoping for a neat way to do it.

```
import re
import csv
fl = open(filename)
line = fl.readline()
coding = re.match('^#\s*coding\s*(:|=|:=)\s*([\w\d\-_]+)\s*$', line)
fl.seek(0)

reader = csv.reader(fl)
# ...
```

Comment: What's "so brutal" about seeking?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: It's another I/O call that can, eventually, be skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your current approach, but here is an alternative that you may find preferable:

```
import re
import csv
import itertools

line = next(f1)
coding = re.match('^#\s*coding\s*(:|=|:=)\s*([\w\d\-_]+)\s*$', line)
reader = csv.reader(itertools.chain([line], f1))
```

It isn't clear from your question or the code you posted, but if you do not want to include the first line if your regex matches you could do the following:

```
reader = csv.reader(f1 if coding else itertools.chain([line], f1))
```

Comment: That's a good one! I didn't know that I can pass any iterable to the `csv.reader` class.

Comment: In general, don't mix `.readline()` and iterator access to file (you might loose data due to buffering). Use `line = next(f1)` instead.

Comment: Requires to handle the `StopIteration` exception that may be thrown by `next()`. Anyway, good answer!